# XNA Diffuse Shader Issue. Strange shadows in places. Image Attached

Tags: c#, xna, shader, shadow, normals

[image: DiffuseShadowIssue]
[image: DiffuseCubeIssue]

As you can see in this image is diffuse shading working correctly in some places but in other places such as the the bottom of the sphere you can see the squares/triangles of
the mesh.

Any idea what would be causing this? Let me know if you need anymore information related to 
code. I can upload my normals calculations and shader effect if required.

EDIT:
Here's a link to the shader I'm using http://pastebin.com/gymVc7CP

Link to normals calculations: http://pastebin.com/KnMGdzHP

Comment: The shading in the "bad" area actually looks like it's mirrored from what it should be.  Did you write the shader yourself?  It looks like it might be calculating something wrong on the "southern hemisphere" incorrectly, possibly the surface normal.

Comment: I've edited the OP to include the shader link. I used one of reimers tutorials and changed it to include normals. I have also tried using BasicEffect for the diffuse and had the same effect. Seems to have the same effect on the northern side of shapes as well though. Can you see anything in the shader I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that all vertices have the same color and proper normals?

Comment: I'm sure the vertices are being coloured the same. As for the normals, I have attached a link to my calculations. I just find it strange that the shading is perfect in some places and not others.